# Find closed formula for the recurrence $a_{n}=na_{n-1}+n(n-1)a_{n-2}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, closed-form

$a_{n}=na_{n-1}+n(n-1)a_{n-2}$ where a0 = 0, a1=1, and n >= 2.

I found an exponential generating function for this recurrence, but cant seem to find the closed form because the generating function doesn't look nice. How would i go aout finding the closed form for this? Thanks

Comment: [OEIS lookup](http://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C+1%2C+2%2C+12%2C+72%2C+600%2C+5760%2C+65520%2C+846720&sort=&language=&go=Search)

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  Let $a_n=n!b_n$. The $b_n$ satisfy a familiar recurrence.