# Strange type of matrix equivalence, $\bf P=Q$. What applications or properties can it have?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, factoring, matrix-decomposition

Stemming from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700473/recurrence-relation-by-linear-algebra?noredirect=1#comment3470490_1700473) when actually searching for matrix similarities, having found this matrix equivalence:

$$\bf A = PBP$$
That is neither transpose nor inversion on either of the $\bf P$s. Just the same matrix from both left and right. I have not found any other properties for the $\bf P$s found but I am curious for any properties it could have and what use they could be of.

As I rarely have seen this type of equivalence before I got curious of where it could pop up when solving problems or making models in science and engineering. Do you have any exciting examples or stories?

---

**EDIT**
Example of a $\bf P$ matrix:

$$\left[\begin{array}{rr}
-1.09067057844122&-0.983363128995121\\
0.0634758169341177&-1.12643972775094
\end{array}\right]$$

I have not managed to find any special structure or property it has yet.

Comment: If $P$ is self-inverse?

Comment: It would be interesting to learn about but I don't think these particular $\bf P$ are self inverse.

Comment: This relation won't be transitive without some conditions on the matrix $P$, which I think would limit its usefulness.

Comment: Is $P$ symmetric/Hermitian, by any chance?

Comment: Not the ones I have found. What if?